# Python Telegram how to catch ValueError in MessageHandler

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a RegEx in a Conversation Handler like this:

```
GET_TELEFONO: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^\+?1?\d{9,15}$'), get_telefono)]
```

what it does is that it checks that the telephone number provided is valid, the problem is that once the user types an incorrect number nothing happens, the user is able to type the phone number again and if it is correct goes to the callback function, what I want to do is that if the phone number is typed incorrectly display a message that the number is incorrect. Is there a way to do a try/except ValueError?

Answer (score 0):

You can e.g. add a second `MessageHandler` to the `GET_TELEFONO` state maybe with `Filters.all` that does the replying. Only first first handler from the list, whos `check_update` method returns `True` will be handled. See the docs of [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html) for details.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.